Do we have $ \displaystyle \sup_{x \in \mathbb R} \left |\sum_j a_j e^{i \lambda_j x}\right|= \sum_j |a_j| $?
Suppose all $a_j \in \mathbb R$ and $ \lambda_j \in \mathbb R$ are distinct. I am interested in the sup-norm of the function $\sum_j a_j e^{i \lambda_j x}$. Is it true that $ \displaystyle \sup_{x \in \mathbb R} \left |\sum_j a_j e^{i \lambda_j x}\right|= \sum_j |a_j| $?
Note that in order for the equality to be true, we would need to find values $x$ where all the elements $e^{i \lambda_j x}$ of the unit circle point approximately in the same direction. Is this always possible or not?

You are using $i$ with two meanings.

@geetha290krm Corrected

$\cos x-\cos 2x$ should work

If the $a_j$ have different signs you need the exponentials corresponding to negative $a_j$  in opposite direction of those corresponding to positive $a_j$ in order to cancel the signs.

Let $n$ be the number of $a_j$'s (or $\lambda_j$'s). Then this is true when $n=1, 2$ but not when $n\ge 3$.
$n=1$ is trivial. As for $n=2$, $$|a_1e^{i\lambda_1 x}+a_2e^{i\lambda_2 x}|=|a_1 + a_2e^{i(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)x}|$$
If $a_1=0$ or $a_2=0$, again it's trivial. Otherwise, because $\lambda_2\not=\lambda_1$, we can choose $x$, such that $e^{i(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)x}=1$ if $a_1/a_2>0$ and $e^{i(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)x}=-1$ if $a_1/a_2<0$, to make sure $|a_1 + a_2e^{i(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)x}|=|a_1|+|a_2|$.
Note that while $\lambda_1\not=\lambda_2$ is essential, $x_1\not=x_2$ is irrelevant.
When $n\ge 3$, consider the following:
$$|\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} je^{i\cdot j \cdot x} - 1 e^{i\cdot 0 \cdot x}|$$
Note that this is a periodic function of $x$ with period $2\pi$, therefore the range is the continuous image of $[0, 2\pi]$ which is compact, that is the supremum can be achieved. If it's equal to $\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j + 1$, that forces $e^{ijx}=-1$ for all $j=1, 2, \cdots, n-1$, or equivalently $\frac{jx}{\pi}$ is an odd integer for all $j=1, 2, \cdots, n-1$. But if $\frac{1\cdot x}{n}$ is an odd integer, then certainly $\frac{2\cdot x}{n}$ is even, a contradiction.

So being distinct is not enough. A sufficient condition for this to hold true is actually $\{1, \lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_n\}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$. Then by the Kronecker's theorem, $(\text{sgn} (a_1), \text{sgn}(a_2), \cdots, \text{sgn} (a_n))$ can be approximated by choosing just integer $x$.

The statement is wrong.
Let $N=4$ and $a=[1,-1,2,-2]$ and $\lambda=[4,-4,8,-8]$ so they are all distinct. Then
$$
f(x)=\sum_{j=1}^N a_j e^{\mathrm{i} \lambda_j x}=\mathrm{i}(2\sin(4x)+4\sin(8x))
$$
Then $\sum_{j=1}^N |a_j|=6$ while
$$
|f(x)|=|2u+8u\sqrt{1-u^2}|=:|g(u)|
$$
where $u=\sin(4x)$. The critical points of $g(u)$ are
$$
\pm \frac{\sqrt{126 + 2\sqrt{129}}}{16}
$$
(from solving $g'(u)=0$) hence
$$
\max |g(u)|=\frac{\sqrt{126+2 \sqrt{129}}\, \left(3+\sqrt{129}\right)}{32}=5.47\dots<6.
$$
